# What punctuation is used to indicate paraphrased dialogue?

Tags: punctuation, indirect-speech, dialogue, paraphrasing

I'm translating a prose work about an epic poem. Instead of quoting dialogues in the original verse form, the author sometimes paraphrases them. What is the standard punctuation for such paraphrased dialogues?

e.g.,

> We know him as a fighter, but when he says I am not ready for combat at this hour, he shows a more nuanced character.

Comment: If it's not a direct quote, perhaps you could use italics?

Comment: *...when he says **he** is not ready...* OR if it's "direct speech", enclose his exact words in quote marks.

Comment: It's probably best to render this << We know him as a fighter, but when he says [(to paraphrase) "I am not ready for combat at this hour," he shows a more nuanced character. // You're never going to give an exact quote anyway if the original is not in English and you translate it.

Comment: Thank you. There are so many such examples throughout the book that I'm afraid using the bracket will over-clutter the text. What about: We know him as a fighter, but when he says, 'I'm not ready for combat at this hour,' he shows a more nuanced character. I could explain the punctuation in the Translator's Note.

Comment: Since you are saying "he says", you don't need anything.

Comment: Once you use quotes, you indicate you are not paraphrasing.

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrase is usually not marked with distinct punctuation or typography in English formatting styles. In academic styles like MLA, APA, or Chicago, one can include a citation after the paraphrased bit to mark the source (see, e.g., APA Style on "[Paraphrasing](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/paraphrasing)"), but in actual publishing such citations are often omitted.

Chicago provides a couple of examples of indirect discourse ([17th edition, 13.45: Indirect discourse](https://www-chicagomanualofstyle-org.us1.proxy.openathens.net/book/ed17/part2/ch13/psec045.html)), or speech that is paraphrased from another text. These examples have no quotation marks. Instead, the syntax of the sentence should make clear what was said:

> Tom told Huck they had to do it that way because the books said so.
>
> Very well, you say, but is there no choice?

One note with the first example: a speaker-referential subject in indirect discourse is usually changed to third person. It is not "Tom told Huck *we* had to do it" (as if Tom was speaking directly to Huck) but "Tom told Huck *they* had to do it." That would change your example to

> We know him as a fighter, but when he says he is not ready for combat at this hour, he shows a more nuanced character.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I'll see if changing the original direct quote to third person will work.